# How can I mark/unmark a Date in Android app

Tags: android-studio, calendar

I'm developing an app for event calendar in android studio. But I want to mark a random date by taping on the date and then pressing the **Mark** Button. Again Unmark the date by clicking the **Unmark** Button.

N.B: I'm currently marking the current date.

Is there any effective solution for my desired criteria?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to maintain your own data structure of which dates are selected. This can be in-memory, persisted via SQLite, etc. There is too little information in your question to give a better answer.

Comment: I use calendar class to create the calendar and thus i get a calendar. Now I want to mark any random date. Like by clicking 26 November 2018 and clicking the Mark button (Mark Button is in the below the calendar).